# BottomExpandableAppBar Fluttter como fazer funcionar

Tags: app, flutter, dart

Galera boa noite, estou com problema ao qual não consigo solucionar, eu estou tentado acrescentar uma barra de menu expansiva na parte de baixo da tela e não está aparecendo quando mando rodar o código

```
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:expandable_bottom_bar/expandable_bottom_bar.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';




  class Mapateste  extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  State<Mapateste> createState() => MapatesteState();
 }

 class MapatesteState extends State<Mapateste> with 
 SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
   BottomBarController controller;
   Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static final CameraPosition myhome = CameraPosition(
  target: LatLng(-23.195874, -45.883488),
  zoom: 14.4746,


);


 @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller = BottomBarController(vsync: this, dragLength: 550, snap: 
  true);
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(   



  body: Stack( 

    children:<Widget>[


      GoogleMap(

        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: myhome,
        ),



      BottomExpandableAppBar(
        controller: controller, 
        expandedHeight: controller.dragLength,
        horizontalMargin: 16,
        expandedBackColor: Color.fromRGBO(16, 6, 144, 1),
      ),

    ],


   );

  }

 }
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).